# vim yank text and paste it displacing existing lines downwards

Tags: vim

Here is the question. Lets say that I have used a visual block to select these 4 lines and then performed "yy".

```
tr
tr
tr
tr
```

Later on I want to paste the yanked text in the line between aaa and bbbb. How to paste the text so that the lines bbbb are displaced downwards?

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa

bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
```

I have read about the command ctrl + R, but when I use it I do not push the lines bbbbb downwards. It appends doing the following.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
tr
trbbbbbbbbb
trbbbbbbbbb
trbbbbbbbbb
```

Nevertheless I would like the following.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
tr
tr
tr
tr
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason you used visual block mode instead of linewise or character visual mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:put`.

From `:h :put` :

```
:[line]pu[t] [x]    Put the text [from register x] after [line] (default
            current line).  This always works |linewise|, thus
            this command can be used to put a yanked block as new
            lines.
```

Answer (score 0):

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) provides various mappings to convert the register types.
The mappings defined by this plugin will allow you to do a character-, line-,
or block-wise paste no matter how you yanked the text, both from normal and
insert mode.